# Error: Statement expected, found py: Dedent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

We are willing/ forced to develop a small Web App for the university. Now we started and everything seems to be fine, until the above strange error raises.

> Statement expected, found py: Dedent

The error is raised by the following lines of code:

```py
def get_reset_token(self, mysql, userid):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""SELECT token FROM tralala_reset_password 
                       WHERE uid=(%s)""", userid)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return data[0]
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger(str(e))
        return ""
```

PyCharm started to mark the `return ""` statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem solved by ignoring the error. Copied to an other editor and nothing here. So seems to be a PyCharm mistake.

Comment: Had the same problem, mine was created by working with code someone wrote in visual studio, copied the content to GUI-Gedit and cleared the .py file and copied it back, fixed

Guessing there were hidden characters pycharm didn't like

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem when you have a lot of files. How can this be fixed when you have hundreds of files?

Comment: Depending on automatic tabs / spaces conversions, this may have modified whitespace.

Answer (score 18):

If you face this issue in PyCharm **2021.2** add the following line

```
-ea
```

to **Help | Edit Custom VM Options ...** or to `<PyCharm_installation_folder>/bin/pycharm.vmoptions` (or `pycharm64.vmoptions`). Restart PyCharm and the parser should work correctly.

See the relevant ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49970

---

**Update:** the fix is available in [2021.2.1 RC](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2021/08/2021-2-1-rc/).

Comment: Thanks for posting here! Looks like this fix worked for me on macOS 11.4.

Comment: this seemed to resolve the same issue with the Python plugin for IntelliJ 2021.2 also

Answer (score 8):

My problem was caused by indentation mismatch. Most of the document was indented with spaces but there were some tabs copied in that caused the Py:DEDENT error. Replacing the tabs with spaces fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

I was also scratching my head for significant period of time and finally figured it out.

The thing is outside of "pycharm did not recognize certain char" scope

When you write this:

```
class Foo:
   def complicated_method(self):
       for f to self.whatever:
           # plenty of code goes here
           pass
   def another one():
       # here too
       pass
```

And then you decide to rewrite it:

```
class Foo:
   def complicated_method(self):
           # plenty of code goes here  <- mistakenly leaved unindented, many unseen errors here
           pass
   def another one(self):
       # here too
       pass
    ....
   def do(self):
       for f in self.whatever:
           self.complicated_method() <- here will be Py:DEDENT
```

Refactor long methods, if you can, and `Py:DEDENT` will never bother you again

Comment: My function isn't long at all, but I have this problem

Comment: @BentaibaMiledBasma cheers
but this especially hard to tackle when there's plenty of unrefactored code u've got to maintain and have no time/ability to rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after upgrading my pycharm-professional snap on Ubuntu 21.*. Fixed it reinstalling pycharm using jetbrains-toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

On PyCharm 2021.2.2 Professional Edition i see the error in following case

```
defthe_fun_one(cls):
 cls.some_module.some_function()

def the_fun_two(cls):
 cls.some_other_module.some_other_function()
```

I see the **Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT** on line `cls.some_other_module.some_other_function()` when a previous function had def not separated by a space typo like `defthe_fun_one(cls):`

Answer (score -1):

- List item

I had an issue where I had an extra -> returnobject in my file. So it was a syntax error.